# Laravel - limiting users for number of posts

Tags: laravel, post, max, limit

Is there any way to limit users in my project for number of posts. For example, I want my users can create a maximum 10 posts each one. So one user has 10 posts? Is it something with `hasMany` or something else? Please help find a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition

> Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests
>   entering your application. For example, Laravel includes a middleware
>   that verifies the user of your application is authenticated. If the
>   user is not authenticated, the middleware will redirect the user to
>   the login screen. However, if the user is authenticated, the
>   middleware will allow the request to proceed further into the
>   application.

To prevent user from adding more than 10 posts you need to create a middleware to protect your `posts/create` route

To create a new middleware, use the make:middleware Artisan command:

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckUserPostsNumber
```

This command will place a new CheckUserPostsNumber class within your `app/Http/Middleware` directory. In this middleware, we will only allow access to the `posts/create` route if the user posts number < than 10. Otherwise, you will redirect the user back to the home URI:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;

class CheckUserPostsNumber
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->posts->count() >= 10) {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Assigning Middleware To Routes**

you would like to assign middleware to specific routes, you should first assign the middleware a key in your app/Http/Kernel.php file. By default, the $routeMiddleware property of this class contains entries for the middleware included with Laravel. To add your own, append it to this list and assign it a key of your choosing:

```
// Within App\Http\Kernel Class...

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    //...
    'checkUserPostsNumber' => 'App\Http\Middleware\checkUserPostsNumber'
];
```

Once the middleware has been defined in the HTTP kernel, you may use the middleware method to assign middleware to a route:

```
Route::get('posts/create', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth', 'checkUserPostsNumber');
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware)

Answer (score 0):

```php
if ($user->posts->count() >= 10) {
  //
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Comment: Please provide an explanation so others can understand how your code *solves* the problem.